# Медленная материализация объектов в Entity Framework 6.1.3

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Пробую Entity Framework и пока что, совершенно не устраивает производительность запроса данных. А точнее скорость материализации объектов. Сам запрос из базы выполняется быстро - 150 мс для 5000 записей. Но вот на материализацию объектов тратися около 500 мс. А пока я не добавил AsNoTracking() то материализация вообще длилась 1500 мс!!!

Для интереса я попробовал Dapper - и с ним на все вместе тратится всего 180 мс!

Код запроса данных при помощи Entity:

```
var dataRecords = context.Records
      .AsNoTracking()
      .Where(r => r.Timestamp >= fromDate && r.Timestamp < toDate)
      .Include(r => r.Product)
      .Include(r => r.Module)
      .Include(r => r.User)
      .Include(r => r.Host)
      .Include(r => r.SourceHost)
      .Include(r => r.Parameter).ToList();
```

Что я делаю не так? Не может же материализация в Entity быть на столько медленнее чем в Dapper.

Ниже собственно сама модель:

```
public class Record
{
  public Record() { }

  public Record(Product product, Module module, Host host, SourceHost sourceHost, User user, Parameter parameter, Journal.Record record)
  {
    Product = product;
    Module = module;
    Host = host;
    SourceHost = sourceHost;
    User = user;
    Parameter = parameter;
    Code = (int)record.Code;
    Timestamp = record.Timestamp;
    ExtendedData = record.ExtendedData;
    TypeOfValue typeOfValue;
    Value = record.EncodeValue(out typeOfValue);
    TypeOfValue = (int)typeOfValue;
  }

  public Code GetCode()
  {
    return (Code)Code;
  }

  public TypeOfValue GetTypeOfValue()
  {
    return (TypeOfValue)TypeOfValue;
  }

  public int RecordId { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public virtual Module Module { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public virtual Host Host { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public virtual SourceHost SourceHost { get; set; }
  public virtual User User { get; set; }
  public virtual Parameter Parameter { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
  public string PreviousValue { get; set; }
  public int TypeOfValue { get; set; }
  [Index(IsUnique = false)]
  public int Code { get; set; }
  [Index(IsUnique = false)]
  public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
  public byte[] ExtendedData { get; set; }
  public string Comment { get; set; }
  public bool Ack { get; set; }
  public DateTimeOffset AckTime { get; set; }
}
```

Остальные классы примитивны и состоят из поля идентификатора Id и строкового поля Name.
[Код проекта с описанием классов модели](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aop7KT-13YTNq2WoIzGNMaWc0TQa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос снят. После переделки запроса на использование анонимного типа скорость стала не хуже чем у Dapper. Т.е. сейчас запрос записей выглядит следующим образом:

```
var recs = context.Records
      .AsNoTracking()
      .Where(r => r.Timestamp >= fromDate && r.Timestamp < toDate)
      .Include(r => r.Product)
      .Include(r => r.Module)
      .Include(r => r.User)
      .Include(r => r.Host)
      .Include(r => r.SourceHost)
      .Include(r => r.Parameter)
      .Select(r => new
      {
        Id = r.RecordId,
        Code = r.Code,
        ProductName = r.Product.ProductName,
        ModuleName = r.Module.ModuleName,
        UserName = r.User.UserName,
        HostName = r.Host.HostName,
        SourceHostName = r.SourceHost.SourceHostName,
        ParameterName = r.Parameter.ParameterName,
        Value = r.Value,
        Timestamp = r.Timestamp,
        Data = r.ExtendedData
      }).ToList();
```

Comment: ведь размер материализованного объекта анонимного типа меньше, чем материализованный объект типа, который получается без оператора Select? Не анонимный же объект дал прирост скорости?

Comment: В том то и дело, что переход на "плоский" анонимный объект и дал такой прирост. Так как когда я сравнивал исходный энтити запрос с Dapper, то там я проецировал все поля всех входящих в модель классов.

Comment: Т.е. почему-то именно необходимость создания дочерних классов Product, Module, User и т.д. вызывало у энтити такие тормоза. Я конечно был готов, что это будет медленней чем Dapper, но не в пять же раз!